# Error opening tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm getting an error opening tensorboard.  This is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant(5,name = 'input_a')
b = tf.constant(3,name = 'input_b')
c = tf.multiply(a,b,name='mul_c')
d = tf.add(a,b,name='add_d')
e = tf.add(c,d,name = 'add_e')
with tf.Session() as sess:
    output = sess.run(e)
    print(output)
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('path/to/log',tf.get_default_graph())
    writer.close()
```

This is the command:

```
tensorboard --logdir=path/to/log
```

This is the ERROR:

> File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
>       exec(code, run_globals)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\tensorboard.exe__main__.py", line 5, in 
>   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\main.py", line 36, in 
>   from tensorboard.plugins.audio import audio_plugin
>   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\audio\audio_plugin.py", line 27, in 
>   from tensorboard import plugin_util
>   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugin_util.py", line 21, in 
>   import bleach
>   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bleach__init__.py", line 14, in 
>   from html5lib.sanitizer import HTMLSanitizer
>   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\html5lib\sanitizer.py", line 7, in 
>    from .tokenizer import HTMLTokenizer
>   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\html5lib\tokenizer.py", line 17, in 
>     from .inputstream import HTMLInputStream
>   File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\html5lib\inputstream.py", line 9, in 
>     from .constants import encodings, ReparseException
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'encodings'

Comment: It looks like you might have an old version of `html5lib` installed... can you try upgrading it using `pip install -U html5lib`?

Answer (score 8):

I got the same error and fixed it. Apparently, there is a problem with `html5lib`, but *mrry*'s suggestion does not solve it because a message will tell you that you already have the latest version installed.

Instead, run this:

```
pip install html5lib==1.0b8
```

More about this issue here: https://github.com/xhtml2pdf/xhtml2pdf/issues/318.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Anaconda. This worked for me:

```
pip uninstall html5lib
conda install -c anaconda html5lib
pip install html5lib==1.0b10
```

Comment: I just used pip uninstall html5lib, and then conda install -c anaconda html5lib. And it works

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by installing python 3.7.2 instead of 3.7.

I also deleted the python file left behind 3.7 in directory `C:\Users\Your_user_name\appdata\local\programs\python` before installing 3.7.2.